# Auto-apply language syntax highlighting for code in Documentation

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, documentation

For Questions and Answers, if you tag the question as a given language, any code blocks in the questions and answers will automatically have syntax highlighting applied for that language.

Is there something similar for documentation?

I added a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1393/subprocess-library) to the *Python Library* documentation tag, but it's not auto-syntax highlighting my code as python.

> EDIT:
>
> It seems like the syntax highlighting is working on approved examples,
>   but not examples pending review.

For example, in an answer

[image: answer screenshot]

But in documentation

[image: documentation screenshot]

Comment: I don't recall Stack Overflow offering something like this before.  It does syntax highlighting by tag, but not necessarily formatting.  It'd be nice, but it's a big ask.

Comment: I'm confused. `lang-py` is being applied to your code blocks on that page...

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I meant syntax highlighting

Comment: @animuson I've included screenshots of what I see when looking at an answer and documentation.  It doesn't appear to be applying the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @animuson Ah, it looks like it's highlighting correctly for the approved examples, but not for the pending review examples

Comment: Yeah, it's an editor bug.  Digging.